# How can I hide Relativelayout on scroll of Linear Layout

Tags: android, layout, scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

Following is my code

Now I want to hide RelativeLayoput On Scroll of NestedScroll
I did it but view fluctuating
with this :
requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.RelativeLayout{4f3557b V.E..

```
nestedScrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {
            Log.d("ScrollView", "scrollX : " + scrollX + " oldScrollX :" + oldScrollX + " scrollY :" + scrollY + " oldScrollY :" + oldScrollY);
            if (scrollY > oldScrollY +20) {
                if(relativeLayout.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE && isTimerStart )
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                if(relativeLayout.getVisibility()==View.GONE && isTimerStart)
                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Did you try using Handler?

Comment: yes I tried but same result if i put more delay its useless